# Magento API .Net: Retrieve product option name-value from order

Tags: .net, magento, soap

I need to know how to retrieve each product's custom options (name/value) in an order.

For example in my order I have 1x product of lets say "Coloured Crayon". 
This product has a custom option of "Colour" which the customer selects when adding the product to their basket.

When I process the customer's order I would like to be able to retrieve the option name and option value.

**Note 1**
Using Magento 1.7 community edition, developing in .Net using SOAP with Magento API v2.

I discovered that a salesOrderEntity Items property called product_options contains what looks like a JSON encoded list of product option VALUES ONLY. This list contains no attribute names but instead has what looks like ID's where I'd think to see option names.

```
salesOrderEntity theOrder = apiService.salesOrderInfo(sSessionId, "100000001");      
string sProductOptions = theOrder.items[0].product_options; // returns JSON like string syntax
```

Comment: I can't even get started calling the Magento API via .NET. If you make progress, could you take a look at this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088459/how-to-call-the-magento-api-from-vb-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation I've discovered that the response I am getting from the product_Options property is serialised php (wth?).

It looks something like this (similar to JSON) if you neaten it up:

```
a:3:{s:7:"colours";a:3:{i:0;s:4:"pink";i:1;s:6:"orange";i:2;s:3:"red";}s:6:"intkey";i:1;s:6:"colour";s:4:"blue";}
```

I've looked around and found a C# php serialiser/deserialiser and have successfully deserialised the response from the API.

[Here is the link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial/) to the C# deserialiser.